# Não está salvando a imagen no caminho

Tags: mysql, python, django, back-end, django-2.0

Estou criando um campo de `ImageField` no django, mas quando coloco pra salvar, ele salva no banco o nome da imagem mas nao salva o caminho para a imagem.

models:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/imagens/', blank=True)
```

---

settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

---

caminho do arquivo:

```
core
 -static
  -geral
  -media
   -imagens
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que me ajudem.

Answer (score 0):

O campo `ImageField` requer a instalação da biblioteca [Pillow](http://from%20django.conf%20import%20settings) para que ele possa fazer a validação da imagem mas se você não quiser/puder instalá-la substitua o `ImageField` por `FileField` no modelo:

```py
...
class Cliente(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='imagens', blank=True)
```

Aliás, a definição para o diretório de mídia não correto pois você está dizendo que ele fica em "core/media" e não em "core/static/media", daí você pode colocar no "settings.py" algo como:

```py
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
```

O se quiser separar o conteúdo estático do de mídia, deixe como está e acrescente no começo "urls.py" da tua aplicação:

```py
from django.conf import settings
```

E na última linha...

```py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Daí o Django irá entendê-lo também como um diretório de conteúdo estático (ou seja, o "/static" e o "/media").